# How to download all the files in a website's directory who are numeroted (1;2;...;97)

Tags: website, wget, httrack

I've been trying to use wget and WinTTrack to download all the .png files who are in a website but I can't seem to find a way to do so. What makes it worse is that I know that all the pictures in the directory are numeroted from 1.png to 97.png ...

Is there any way to do this? I'd really appreciate ^_^

Answer (score 0):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) should do the job:

```
curl "http://www.example.com/dir/[1-97].png" -o "#1.png"
```